# Writing apache module for filtering HTTP request on PHP website

Tags: php, apache, module

I'm going to make simple web application firewall like modsecurity. I want to write apache module in C for filtering a web attack like SQL injection.

I put my web on `http://localhost/vulweb`
my question is, when iam accessing `http://localhost/vulweb` i want the apache module analysis the request first, before continuing its to PHP website (if the request is not an attack).
Can anyone help me to explain how to make a module for this purpose? and how to configure this module (sethandler, addhandler)??

PS: I have already know how to write helloworld apache module with C, and run it through `http://localhost/helloworld`

Comment: Is there a particular reason for not using mod_security?

Comment: this is for my research purpose, i am going to write a WAF with machine learning approach